# How to 301 redirect http:// to https:// for specific URLs (not typical example)

Tags: .htaccess

When editing the htaccess file...

How can you 301 redirect:

```
old url: http://example.com/old-long-url/
new url: https://example.com/new-url/
```

(note the difference in the protocol identifier, from http to https, for the target URL)

Every example I have found so far, does not allow for the start of the 301 code to target the http part.

Currently every http:// is redirected to https://... which means whenever I change a specific URL, I end up with a redirect chain.

E.G

```
http://example.com/old-url/
```

Redirects to..

```
https://example.com/old-url/
```

(due to the code that redirects every http to https)

And finally that gets redirected to:

```
https://example.com/new-url/
```

I hope that makes sense. It is confusing to me!

Comment: OK. I have been told that this is impossible to do.